# Unity - Problem with Holding Mouse Button Multiple times

Tags: unity-game-engine

A little background: I am making a small bit of game that involves clicking and dragging a clock hand to add time to a bank. The issue I'm having is with the clicking and dragging process. After an amount of time or multiple clicks, clicking on the clock face no longer works to make the variable "isActive" true. I've confirmed that it stops working somewhere in the code below and not in the code that checks isActive. Thanks for the help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClockFace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isActive = false;
    public bool isAble = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isActive)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonUp("Fire1"))
            {
                isActive = false;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            if  (isAble)
            {
                isActive = true;
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Mouse"))
        {
            isAble = true;
        }        
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Mouse"))
        {
            isAble = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen when your mouse leaves the clock while holding the button pressed? That's what could trigger the behaviour you described in the code you provided.

Comment: It does not happen exclusively when that happens. Pretty much just happens, as far as I can tell, just kinda randomly but with high probability after like 30 seconds. After some print statements to check isActive and isAble, its just the isActive that stops turning on.

Comment: Really odd, I'm not sure you'll be able to get any help without a fully reproducible version available. Things that happen at random are hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Unitys old imput system is't very good now that the new imput system is out. It comes in the unity 2019.3 update, but you can install it from the package manager in earlier versions. I recomend to use that.

Comment: Companies/people have made billions using that same input system so far... it's not ideal, but it's definitely not having random bugs like the one OP described. This is definitely not the answer to the question.